# Sending HTTP POST request mistake

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-headers

I'm having problems in getting a JSON properly. This is how I query the database.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myURL.com/list?key=%@", myKey]

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL
                                             URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection;
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

with

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {

    NSMutableData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    [receivedData appendData:data];

    NSString *stringr;

    stringr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Get string %@", stringr);

    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *thejson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Get dict %@", thejson); ///THIS RESULTS NULL
}
```

From the Get string NSLog I get two responses. I explain better. If I type my request URL in the browser, I see the entire JSON response, while from my NSLog I get a part of response and another part still in the same NSLog but after some time than the first NSLog.

For example: 2014-10-11 19:38:58.401 Myapp[1607:365755] Get dict (here I get the first part of my JSON)

2014-10-11 19:38:58.401 Myapp[1607:365755] Get dict (here I get the second and final part of my JSON).

Why I don't get one and entire NSLog reply ? I am sure I'm mistaking something but I really don't know what. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it may take multiple calls to `didReceiveData` to process this, you should separate the receiving of the data from the parsing of it:

1. Create `NSMutableData` property:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *receivedData;
   ```
2. Before starting the connection, initialize it:

   ```
   self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   ```
3. In `receivedData` do nothing but appending the data:

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
       [self.receivedData appendData:data];

       // if you want to log it, you can do:

       NSString *stringr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"Get string %@", stringr);
   }
   ```
4. Only try to parse it in:

   ```
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {    
       NSError *error;

       NSDictionary *thejson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

       NSLog(@"Get dict %@", thejson); ///THIS SHOULD NOT FAIL IF VALID JSON
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code. for me is working very well and this is Asynchronous (for my better).

```
    -(void)preparePostHttpRequestAsynchronous:(NSURL*)urlString
                                        json:(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonDictionary
                               andIdentifier:(NSInteger)identifier
    {

        NSString *newUrlString = [jsonDictionary jsonStringFromDictionary:jsonDictionary ];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];
        NSString *post = newUrlString;
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setTimeoutInterval: 20];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *data, NSError *e)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error %@",e);

             if (e || !data){
                 NSLog (@"Error %@",e);
                 return;
             }

             NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

             NSMutableDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|kNilOptions error:&jsonParsingError];

             // here you can do whatever with your data
             // i recomend you to use a Protocol or something like that

         }];

    }
```

If you use my code i recommend you create a protocol to receive the answers. you have an example of this in https://github.com/sampayo/just-eat-restaurants this is the class [RequestHelper.m](https://github.com/sampayo/just-eat-restaurants/blob/master/IntelligentposTest/RequestHelper.m)